# Problems not working QCanBus

Tags: qt, can-bus

Problems not create  Can Bus Device, create project Qt 5.10 why not create ?? 
package serialbus be connected. CAN be connected across USB.  IIts so hard. My life its harded. I'm a national minority, I'm not as clever as white masters, please do not grieve for me.

can bus Device not working

[image]

file.pro

```
QT       += core gui serialbus

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = CAN_simple_experiment
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS    

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSerialBus>
#include <QCanBus>
#include <QCanBusDevice>

#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
int i  = 0;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
        // Create device.
         QCanBusDevice *device = 
          QCanBus::instance()>createDevice("socketcan","vcan0");

        if (device != nullptr){
            qDebug() << "Created device, state is:" << device->state();
            ui->textEdit->append("Created device, state is:"+ device->state());
        } else {
            qFatal("Unable to create CAN device.");
            ui->textEdit->append("Unable to create CAN device.");
        }
        //Connect.
        if(device->connectDevice()){
            qDebug() << "Connected, state is:" << device->state();
             ui->textEdit->append("Connected, state is:"+ device->state());
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Connect failed, error is:" << device->errorString();
            ui->textEdit->append("Connect failed, error is:"+ device->errorString());
        }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your CAN device is recognized by your PC ?
are you sure that its name is "vcan0" on windows ?

Comment: first you can try this example :
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtserialbus-can-example.html

Comment: @marouane18 
 he writes to me "  Сannot load library pcanbasic: Unknown error 0x000000c1"
  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825860/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pcan-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-usb-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to check SocketCAN interfaces that can be used check [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qcanbus.html#details).

```
QString errorString;
const QList<QCanBusDeviceInfo> devices = QCanBus::instance()->availableDevices(
    QStringLiteral("socketcan"), &errorString);
if (!errorString.isEmpty())
    qDebug() << errorString;
```

You can't create the device if the list is empty (watch the errorString);

```
// Create device.
if (devices.count())
   QCanBusDevice *device = 
      QCanBus::instance()>createDevice("socketcan","vcan0");
```

Comment: gives me the answer: No such plugin: 'socketcan'

Comment: @timob256, thats an indication you dont have SocketCAN interfaces available

Answer (score 0):

There is no support of socketcan on Windows.
There are Linux specific calls inside socketcanbackend.cpp:

```
#include <linux/can/error.h>
#include <linux/can/raw.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
...
if (Q_UNLIKELY(ioctl(canSocket, SIOCGSTAMP, &timeStamp) < 0)) {
...
```

etc